# How do I ensure that a timed loop performs the same number of iterations from trial to trial when the same duration is specified?

Tags: python, timedelta

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ntrials = 3                                                    # specify number of trials
duration = 1                                                   # specify duration (in seconds)

for i in range(1,ntrials+1):
    count = 0                                                  # (re)initialize count to zero
    end_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=duration)    # set trial duration
    while datetime.now() < end_time:                           # check if duration has elapsed
         count += 1                                            # count number of iterations
    print("trial: ",i,"\tcount: ",count)                       # display results
```

Comment: The number could vary depending on the other tasks that the computer is doing. It will vary. That is normal.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).